# Check if the lastest entry in my table is between two dates in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a User model and an Order model which has a createdAt column.

Order belongs to User.

I want to get all the users where the most recent order (based on createdAt) is between **two dates**.

Is it possible with Sequelize?